# I need to load a json file into a data structure using python. Why is my code failing?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, normalize

My data looks like this...

```
with open("./tmp/json_file.json") as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        print(line)
```

> {"metadata": {"schemaVersion": 1, "recordGeneratedBy": "rsu", "recordGeneratedAt": "2019-10-30 15:00:00.019 [ET]", "logFileName": "2019_10_30_15_thea16.csv", "kind": "out", "psid": "32770", "RSUID": "thea16", "externalID": "NA", "dataType": "spat"}, "payload": {"data": {"SPAT": {"timeStamp": "436020", "intersections": {"IntersectionState": {"id": {"id": "59425"}, "revision": "120", "status": "0000000000000000", "timeStamp": "17", "states": {"MovementState": [{"signalGroup": "2", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"stop-And-Remain": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "171"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "4", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"protected-Movement-Allowed": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "114"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "9", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"stop-And-Remain": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "171"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "10", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"protected-clearance": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "114"}}}}]}}}}}}}

> {"metadata": {"schemaVersion": 1, "recordGeneratedBy": "rsu", "recordGeneratedAt": "2019-10-30 15:00:00.131 [ET]", "logFileName": "2019_10_30_15_thea16.csv", "kind": "out", "psid": "32770", "RSUID": "thea16", "externalID": "NA", "dataType": "spat"}, "payload": {"data": {"SPAT": {"timeStamp": "436020", "intersections": {"IntersectionState": {"id": {"id": "59425"}, "revision": "121", "status": "0000000000000000", "timeStamp": "128", "states": {"MovementState": [{"signalGroup": "2", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"stop-And-Remain": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "171"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "4", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"protected-Movement-Allowed": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "114"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "9", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"stop-And-Remain": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "171"}}}}, {"signalGroup": "10", "state-time-speed": {"MovementEvent": {"eventState": {"protected-clearance": null}, "timing": {"minEndTime": "114"}}}}]}}}}}}}

I am trying to normalize it using the following code:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

file_json = json.load(open(local_directory + "json_file.json","r"))
result = json_normalize(data=file_json, meta=['metadata', ['payload', 'data']])
result.head()
```

But I am getting the following error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 1 (char 1014)

What could be causing the error? Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: You have an invalid JSON file, there can only be one top-level key/value structure and your file has one every line. Split the file on newlines and parse each of the individual lines, then go yell at the person who made the "JSON" file for general cluelessness.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use json_normalize, your 'json'-file (which isnt really a json-file then) should be of type `[{..},{..}]`.

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for the docs about json_normalize.